# How to create the specified data structure in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdictionary

I am trying to create a particular data structure as specified below in Swift.

```
[{"productId":1,"qty":3},{"productId":2,"qty":1},{"productId":3,"qty":5},{"productId":4,"qty":30},{"productId":5,"qty":13}]
```

Can some one guide me how to achive it..... I need to add and remove the data structure.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Are you aiming to work with it as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

It is an `Array of Dictionaries`.

Define it like this :

```
var dataStructure = [[String: Any]]()
```

To add something :

```
var newData = [String: Any]()
newData["productId"] = 1
newData["qty"] = 1
dataStructure.append(newData)
```

To delete :

```
dataStructure.remove(at: indexYouWantTodeleteInInt)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called as dictionary in swift.

The declaration part can be as follows:

```
var params: [String:Any]
```

We can also use like:

```
var params: [String:Any] = ["user_id" : AppConfiguration.current.user_id]
```

Now to add key-value pair in it you can do as follows:

```
    params["form_id"] = form_id!
    params["parent_category_id"] = id 
    params["device_token"] = getDeviceToken()
    params["app_version"] = APP_VERSION
    params["app_device_type"] = originalDeviceType
```

to remove a key-value pair:

```
    params.removeValue(forKey: "parent_category_id")
```

to update any value of particular key:

```
    params.updateValue("10", forKey: "form_id")
```

if the above key is already present it updates the value and if not then it adds a new key to the dictionary

The Above explained part is dictionary. Now you need the data-structure as array of dictionary so you need to declare as

```
var params: [[String:Any]]
```

you can perform all the operations you can perform on an array but the value you will get at a particular index will be of type dictionary which I explained above.

Hope this helps you understand what is dictionary and what is array of dictionaries.

In your case you can also write `[String: Int]` instead of `[String:Any]' but it will restrict you to only have integer values with respect to the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Swift developers usually use Structs in order to create a data structure from a JSON reponse. From Swift 4, JSON parsing has become very easy. Thanks to Codable protocols.

From the above given answer, you can create something like this.

```
MyStruct.Swift

import Foundation

typealias MyStruct = [[String: Int]]
```

You can then parse by calling the following method.

```
   let myStruct = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: jsonData)
```

You can add value by using this.

```
var newProduct = [String: Any]()
newProduct["productId"] = 941
newProduct["qty"] = 2
myStruct.append(newProduct)
```

To remove the data

```
myStruct.remove(at:"Some index")
```